# I don't see in the sidebar the Azure Tools extension install in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have installed Azure Tools but I don't see it

[image]

It appears in the list of installed extensions but it has a circle with an 8 that I don't understand

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: "_but it has a circle with an 8 that does not mean_" error: failed to parse. this is not a grammatical english statement. that does not mean what?

Answer (score -1):

Solved reinstalling the extension again

[image]